# Nested select statement in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have two tables a messages and a comments sections.  A messages can have many comments, but a comments can only have one message.  I am trying to write a sql select statement that would return the message and all comments referring to that message in one row.  Is there a way to do that in mysql?  How would I go about it.  The comments has a message id which is a foreign key that relates to the id of messages. Here is my ERD diagram

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use group_concat and for group_concat you need group by

```
SELECT message, GROUP_CONCAT(comment SEPARATOR ';') as  comments
FROM   messages 
JOIN   comments  ON messages .id = comments  .message_id
GROUP By message
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function:

```
SELECT   message, GROUP_CONCAT(comment SEPARATOR ';') AS all_comments
FROM     messages m
JOIN     comments c ON m.id = c.message_id
GROUP BY m.id, message
```